# background clip text is not working in IE

Tags: html, css

I have requirement to display the text in a gradient format. Below is the example

Html

```
<div class="banner">Free account</div>
```

css

```
.banner{
    font-family: Univers LT Std Bold;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* background: lightblue; */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right,#00853f 20%, #8cc63f 80%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(right,#00853f 20%, #8cc63f 80%);
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

The problem is in IE the "background-clip: text;" is not working. Please suggest how to resolve this or please suggest is there any alternative way.

Comment: Which version of IE?  It's supported in IE11 and Edge.  You are also using the vendor prefix specifically for Chrome so you cannot expect that to work in IE at all.

Comment: Perhaps you are using a browser that does not support this property.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

According to http://caniuse.com/#search=background-clip, `background-clip` is only supported in IE11 or later. It won't work in earlier versions of IE.

Also, from the code you've shared it doesn't look like you are actually using the `background-clip` property but rather `-webkit-background-clip`. That vendor-prefixed property will only work for Webkit browsers (e.g., Chrome, Safari). You need to add the standard property as well.

There are polyfills to help workaround this. Here's an example from https://codepen.io/TimPietrusky/pen/cnvBk:

```js
 /**
  -webkit-background-clip: text Polyfill
  
  # What? #
  A polyfill which replaces the specified element with a SVG
  in browser where "-webkit-background-clip: text" 
  is not available.

  Fork it on GitHub
  https://github.com/TimPietrusky/background-clip-text-polyfill

  # 2013 by Tim Pietrusky
  # timpietrusky.com
**/

Element.prototype.backgroundClipPolyfill = function () {
  var a = arguments[0],
      d = document,
      b = d.body,
      el = this;

  function hasBackgroundClip() {
    return b.style.webkitBackgroundClip != undefined;
  };
  
  function addAttributes(el, attributes) {
    for (var key in attributes) {
      el.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]);
    }
  }
  
  function createSvgElement(tagname) {
    return d.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tagname);
  }
  
  function createSVG() {
    var a = arguments[0],
        svg = createSvgElement('svg'),
        pattern = createSvgElement('pattern'),
        image = createSvgElement('image'),
        text = createSvgElement('text');
    
    // Add attributes to elements
    addAttributes(pattern, {
      'id' : a.id,
      'patternUnits' : 'userSpaceOnUse',
      'width' : a.width,
      'height' : a.height
    });
    
    addAttributes(image, {
      'width' : a.width,
      'height' : a.height
    });
    image.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', a.url);
    
    addAttributes(text, {
      'x' : 0,
      'y' : 80,
      'class' : a['class'],
      'style' : 'fill:url(#' + a.id + ');'
    });
    
    // Set text
    text.textContent = a.text;
      
    // Add elements to pattern
    pattern.appendChild(image);
      
    // Add elements to SVG
    svg.appendChild(pattern);
    svg.appendChild(text);
    
    return svg;
  };
  
  /*
   * Replace the element if background-clip
   * is not available.
   */
  if (!hasBackgroundClip()) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      var svg = createSVG({
        'id' : a.patternID,
        'url' : a.patternURL,
        'class' : a['class'],
        'width' : this.width,
        'height' : this.height,
        'text' : el.textContent
      });
      
      el.parentNode.replaceChild(svg, el);
    }
    img.src = a.patternURL;
  }
};

var element = document.querySelector('.headline'); 

/*
 * Call the polyfill
 *
 * patternID : the unique ID of the SVG pattern
 * patternURL : the URL to the background-image
 * class : the css-class applied to the SVG
 */
element.backgroundClipPolyfill({
  'patternID' : 'mypattern',
  'patternURL' : 'http://timpietrusky.com/cdn/army.png',
  'class' : 'headline'
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url(http://timpietrusky.com/cdn/army.png) repeat;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

/*
 * This style will be shared with the SVG because
 * I have to replace the DOM element in Firefox. 
 * Otherwise the SVG pattern will be broken.
 */
.headline {
  font: bold 2.25em sans-serif;
}

svg {
  height: 8em;
  width: 100%;
}

/*
 * Just some styling... ignore it
 */
article {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-top: .15em solid #7BB03B;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5794C7;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out;
}
a:hover {
  color: #7BB03B;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="headline">-webkit-background-clip: text | Polyfill</h1>

<article>
  <p>
    <a href="https://github.com/TimPietrusky/background-clip-text-polyfill" target="_blank">Fork it on GitHub</a>
  </p>
  
  <p>
    2013 by <a href="https://twitter.com/TimPietrusky" target="_blank">@TimPietrusky</a>
  </p>
</article>
```

Comment: That's not how caniuse works. Click on the Show All button to see that it is supported back through IE9.

Comment: @Donutself To clarify, `background-clip` is supported, however `background-clip: text` is not. The reason it still shows green and not yellow for partially supported is probably because `text` is still considered experimental.

Answer (score 0):

i can back on the claim that IE is not supporting it.
Here is a test site i am working on: http://hot.o-zen.de/

Code is used on the Paragraph Titles (the ones with yellow squares):

```
<h1>[icon color="#FFE729" icon="kt-icon-stop" size="70px" float="left"]<span class="innershadow">DIE PRAXEN</span></h1>

.innershadow {
  background-color: #000;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -moz-background-clip: text;
      background-clip: text;
}
```

on IE 11 this shows just a black rectangle, on Edge, the text is just black, on Chrome and Firefox it looks great.

Best regard,
B.Anders

Comment: i just used @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) to make ie11 see another css

Comment: I couldn't get the above code to work for my background-clip: text for IE.