# CSS animation differs in browsers

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, css-animations

Created two animations using `CSS` & `SVG`.
They are working well in **Chrome**, but *not* working as expected in **Internet Explorer**.

Chrome Screenshot

[image: Chrome Screen Shot]

Internet Explorer Screenshot

[image: Internet Explorer Screen Shot]

My Codes:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #000fe6, #000);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80%;
  animation: animate 3.75s linear infinite;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(45, 45, 45, .05);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position: -500%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500%;
  }
}

svg {
  display: flex;
  font: 10.5em 'Montserrat';
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.text-copy {
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-dasharray: 6% 29%;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
  animation: stroke-offset 5.5s infinite linear;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(1) {
  stroke: #4D163D;
  animation-delay: -1;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(2) {
  stroke: #840037;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(3) {
  stroke: #BD0034;
  animation-delay: -3s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(4) {
  stroke: #BD0034;
  animation-delay: -4s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(5) {
  stroke: #FDB731;
  animation-delay: -5s;
}

@keyframes stroke-offset {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -35%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h3>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 960 300">
 <symbol id="s-text">
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="80%">Title</text>
 </symbol>

 <g class = "g-ants">
  <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
 </g>
</svg>
    </h3>
    <p>Some text here</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Run the result of the code on different browsers to understand the mistake. The correct result will be in Latest Chrome.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oweLs903)

---

**Title** is animated in SVG format, looks cool in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer.

**Some text here** is animated with the help of CSS, looks cool in Chrome, but it's not as expected in Internet Explorer.

Comment: IE does not support CSS animation of SVG elements. Please refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812303/svg-animation-is-not-working-on-ie11

Comment: Ok, and what about **Some text here**? (CSS animation)

Comment: [background clip text is not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275608/background-clip-text-is-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: So, what can be alternative methods for both?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/  Refer this site to know about browser support for the css3 properties you are using.

Comment: **Alternative method**: Your code produce a fancy aesthetical output. You may choose to use a plain unanimated svg in those browsers that do not `@supports` CSS animation on SVG elements or background clip text.

Comment: @enxaneta I tried `@supports (stroke-dasharray: 6% 29%;
) {
  .text-copy {
    stroke-dasharray: 6% 29%;
  }
}` but it then shows normal on supported browsers too... refer https://jsfiddle.net/oweLs903/1/

Comment: Try `@supports (stroke-dasharray: 6% 29%)` instead of `@supports (stroke-dasharray: 6% 29%; )`. Delete the semicolon `;`